# Блаженніший чи блаженнійший, святіший чи святійший

Tags: орфографія

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_(%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) подає `Блаженнійший митрополит Київський і всієї України Епіфаній`. Але в [інших](https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/29746455.html?fbclid=IwAR3MQ_LltkdXNcUxLXFkjMc1Ki4BRK1ACdxsnjWzCfZyNSnBZcm3-MgazHU) джерелах зустрічається `Блаженніший`. Як правильніше? А також чи мають писатися ці слова з великої літери?

Аналогічне питання і стосовно слова `святі(й)ший`. [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) подає в одному місці `Святіший Патріарх Київський і всієї Руси-України`, а в іншому на тій же сторінці - `Святійший Патріарх Київський і всієї Руси-України Філарет`.

Answer (score 2):

[«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) кажуть, що без *-й-*.

А «Словник української мови» в 20 томах каже, що *[блаженні(й)ший](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=152865&page=176)* можна обома способами, але першим наводить варіант без *-й-*. (Слова *святі(й)ший* він зовсім не наводить, бо видається поступово й томів на *С-* ще не має.)

Отже: якщо писатимете без *-й-*, то точно не помилитеся.

*Дивніший*, *добріший*, *консервативніший*, *красивіший*, *сильніший*, *сміливіший*, *ясніший* тощо зараз без *-й-* пишеться, хоча в старих книжках може бути з *-й-*. Етимологічно там, здається, має бути *-й-*, але сучасний правопис у цьому аспекті більше орієнтується на вимову, ніж на етимологію. Мабуть, затримці *-й-* у словах *святі(й)ший*, *блаженні(й)ший* сприяло те, що в релігійних контекстах люди зазвичай консервативніші, а мовою літургії значною мірою була церковнослов'янська.

<sub>Мене особисто дивує відсутність префікса *най-*, адже українською без *най-* зазвичай вищий (comparative) ступінь, а найвищий (superlative) зазвичай із *най-* (це російською comparative *красивее* і superlative *красивейший*, а українською comparative *красивіший* і superlative *найкрасивіший*). А за семантикою, здається, тут має бути найвищий (superlative) ступінь, бо інакше б виникало питання «*блажінніший/святіний* від кого (за кого, ніж хто)?». Чи так історично склалося чи це калька з російської/церковнослов'янської, я не знаю.</sub>